# laravel mix.js rendering - keep folder structure with wildcards

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I'm using Laravel with React.jsx. My `webpack.mix.js` file looks like this:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

if ( ! mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.webpackConfig({
        devtool: 'source-map'
    })
}

mix.react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .react('resources/js/*.jsx', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

This is working exactly as I expect - any `.jsx` file directly in `resources/js/`gets compiled correctly into `public/js/`

What I want now, though, I'm struggling with. I want every .jsx file that in `resources/js/pages/`, AND every one of its subfolders, to be compliled and put into a matching folder in `public/js/`

So for example if I have a file `resources/js/pages/a.jsx`, I want it in `public/js/pages/a.js`, and if I have a file `resources/js/pages/x/y/z/file.jsx`, I of course naturally want it to appear in `public/js/pages/x/y/z/file.js`

I thought I could achieve this with wildcards, so I tried this:

`mix.react('resources/js/pages/*/*.jsx', 'public/js')`

However, that only went exactly one folder deep (eg into `resources/js/pages/x/`), didn't render anything directly in `resources/js/pages`, and put all the rendered files into `public/js` rather than keeping the subfolder structure.

Is there any way to achieve what I want? A sort of recursive folder/file wildcard that keeps the folder structure when putting into `/public/js/`?

Comment: Have you tried `mix.react('resources/js/pages/**/*.jsx', 'public/js')`?

Comment: @GeorgeHanson I'll give it a go

Comment: @GeorgeHanson nope, it actually did the same thing as `.react('resources/js/*.jsx', 'public/js')` which surprised me a little bit